# An explanation about overriding SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I've been studying java and Spring for a while, during my spare time so I neither master java nor Spring yet.

For the web project I created to study java and Spring I had to extends the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandlerm`.

What it's not clear to it's why after extending `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` and overriding `onAuthenticationFailure`, in my own `onAuthenticationFailure()...` method I had to call the `super.onAuthenticationFailure(...)`  method.

Probably I didn't get one of the main rule of java.

Here is the class i was talking about

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler { 

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {    

       if(exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(BadCredentialsException.class)) {
              setDefaultFailureUrl("/url1");
        }

       else if (exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(DisabledException.class)) {        
            setDefaultFailureUrl("/url2");
       }

       else if (exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(SessionAuthenticationException.class)) {      
            setDefaultFailureUrl("/url3");  
      }

      super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);  //why this???
    }    
}
```

Comment: What exactly you do before calling super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);?

Comment: I edited my post. Anyway, I check the type of exception and I redirect the user to a specific page.

Comment: Here you are setting only the default url. So you need to write the logic for redirecting when the failure happens. That logic is written in SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler class. So you need to call  super.onAuthenticationFailure method.

Comment: I hope you are clear with my answer.

Comment: Just to try/study I copied the original source code of onAuthenticationFailure() inside my own onAuthenticationFailure() and now I don't need anymore to call super.onAuthenticationFailure().
Thank you again

Comment: Yes absolutely. But if you are writing the same piece of code in your CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler then use super.onAuthenticationFailure().

Comment: I should call super.onAuthenticationFailure() even if I had copied and pasted the original code of onAuthenticationFailure() inside my own onAuthenticationFailure()?? If i copied the original code of onAuthenticationFailure() I have already the logic of that method. Don't I?

Comment: No need to call again if you copy paste the method from the super class to your class.

Comment: Please refer this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are trying to override the method of SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.

This method is defined in SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler:

```
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (this.defaultFailureUrl == null) {
            this.logger.debug("No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error");
            response.sendError(401,"Authentication Failed: " + exception.getMessage());
        } else {
            saveException(request, exception);

            if (this.forwardToDestination) {
                this.logger.debug("Forwarding to " + this.defaultFailureUrl);
                request.getRequestDispatcher(this.defaultFailureUrl).forward(request, response);
            } else {
                this.logger.debug("Redirecting to " + this.defaultFailureUrl);
                this.redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response,
                        this.defaultFailureUrl);
            }
        }
    }
```

In your CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler you are overriding the method of SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler:

Basically here you are only setting the default url. And you need to write the redirect strategy. But it is defined in the super class SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler. So you need to call super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);